# calculate difference between two double values exactly

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the difference between two double values

for example : lat1=12.2345673 and lat2=12.2345672 . here i want result as 0.0000001. this much exactly i am not getting while calculate double res=Double.compare(lat1,lat2) in eclipse. it showing 0.0.
Please specify the exact formula to overcome this

Comment: questions of this nature have been asked countless times on SO. Whenever you work with floating point you need to work to a tolerance, not exact values.

Comment: Double.compare is also not intended to calculate the difference. It is useful for ordering. Is the left value less than, equal to, or greater than the right value? The method returns an *integer*. You are using the wrong tool.

Comment: hi , thanks for replying.. here we cant find directly like this.? hw to find tolerance here between two latitude values. lat1=12.2345673 and lat2=12.2345672 . here i want result as 0.0000001

Comment: See also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can u try the following code ,

```
     double lat1=12.2345673;
     double lat2=12.2345672;
     double dif=lat1-lat2;

     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#######");
     System.out.println("Diff Val  : "+df.format(dif));
```

Output :
Diff Val  : 0.0000001

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method for calculating distance between two lat-long points.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param lat1 Latitude of the First Location
 * @param lng1 Logitude of the First Location
 * @param lat2 Latitude of the Second Location
 * @param lng2 Longitude of the Second Location
 * @return distance between two lat-lon in float format
 */

public static float distFrom (float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2 ) 
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```

Comment: hi , thanks for replying.. here we cant find directly like this.? hw to find tolerance here between two latitude values.  lat1=12.2345673 and lat2=12.2345672 . here i want result as 0.0000001.

Comment: you mean you want long decimal precision value ?

Comment: yes,  i want the result as specified .any formula to give exact result.? i did with double d=Double.compare(lat1,lat2) but it giving result as 0.0 instead of 0.0000001. i did in eclipse. how to get exact result

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both numbers by 10 million, then subtract, then divide by same would be one solution.

Turn it into an int.

Answer (score 1):

When I work with Lat/Long values I usually work with 1E6 accuracy and store as an int. 
I learned this pattern from the GeoPoint class in Google's Android Map library.

Looks like you need more than 1E6 though, so you might want to use higher accuracy and use long instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).